# The issue encountered when using the baseband service to send and receive data

Tags: unetstack

When using groovy, if we want to send a baseband signal, we need to convert the signal into an alternating form of real and imaginary parts before sending it. This is because groovy does not support complex number representation. However, when using Python APIs to call Unetstack, if we want to send a baseband signal using TXbasebandSignalReq, do we still need to convert it into an alternating form of real and imaginary parts, even though Python supports complex number representation?

I would be extremely grateful if someone could help me address this question.

Answer (score 2):

No, `unetpy` supports complex signals in `TxBasebandSignalReq` and so you don't need to manually interleave the real/imaginary parts. You can see an example at https://github.com/org-arl/unet-contrib/blob/master/unetsocket/python/python-gateway-tutorial.ipynb